# Kivy layouts don't display buttons correctly

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a keypad sort of thing in kivy, by arranging 9 buttons in a 3x3 GridLayout. However, after running the code, it only shows 1 button in the bottom right corner.

My code:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App

class root(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.rows = 2
        self.button1 = Button(text = '1')
        self.button2 = Button(text = '2')
        self.button3 = Button(text = '3')
        self.button4 = Button(text = '4')
        self.button5 = Button(text = '5')
        self.button6 = Button(text = '6')
        ...........
        self.add_widget(self.button1)
        self.add_widget(self.button2)
        self.add_widget(self.button3)
        self.add_widget(self.button4)
        ...........


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        l = root()
        return l

myApp().run()
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you know how to use the .kv language? I think that one simple solution would be to implement the .kv language in a separate file which would make layouts simpler.

Comment: I do know KV, but i prefer pure python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following errors:

- To import `GridLayout` you must use `from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout`
- When you use `super()` you must pass as the first parameter the name of the class, that is, `super(root, self).__init__(**kwargs)`.
- You say you want 3 rows and 3 columns, so you should use `self.cols = 3`, `self.rows = 3`.

Code:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App

class root(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(root, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 3
        self.rows = 3
        self.button1 = Button(text = '1')
        self.button2 = Button(text = '2')
        self.button3 = Button(text = '3')
        self.button4 = Button(text = '4')
        self.button5 = Button(text = '5')
        self.button6 = Button(text = '6')
        ...........
        self.add_widget(self.button1)
        self.add_widget(self.button2)
        self.add_widget(self.button3)
        self.add_widget(self.button4)
        ...........


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        l = root()
        return l

myApp().run()
```

---

A simpler and more elegant solution is to use a for-loop:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Root(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Root, self).__init__(**kwargs, rows=3, cols=3)

        for i in range(1, 10):
            btn = Button(text=str(i))
            self.add_widget(btn)


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        l = Root()
        return l


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve it. And I did try the for loop first, but then when I had the same problem, i tried to add them manually.

Comment: And the import error was just an error when I was copy pasting the code from my editor.